# How to use window.onerror within a react component?

Tags: reactjs

i am planning to log all the console errors from my reactjs application to file using window.onerror.

So i have the main component from which the application starts and created another component ErrorLog which will have this window.onerror. But i am not sure how to use this window.onerror within the react component. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Below is my code,

```
class ErrorLog extends react.purecomponent {
    state = {
        error_log: [];
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        window.onerror();
    }
    render = () => {
        return (
        );
    };
}
```

Now the question is how to define the window.onerror method within componentDidMount lifecycle hook such that it gives me the linenumber, msg and error (basically what is essential to be logged into a file).

I am new to adding these javascript errors to the a log file..Could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple adding of event listener should work.

```
class ErrorLog extends react.purecomponent {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
            error_log: [];
         };

         this.handleErrorEnter = this.handleErrorEnter.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       window.onerror = this.handleErrorEnter;
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        //Remove here
    }

    handleErrorEnter = (message, source, lineno, colno, error) => {
        console.log("Error message, source, lineno, colno, error:", message, source, lineno, colno, error);
    }

    render = () => {
       return (
       );
    };
}
```

Comment: event is not logged to console...since event is undefined.

Comment: ya, you can change them to parameters defined in the function, edited.

Comment: yep it works now...i changed them as suggested...so now what would be the best approach to do..so when there is an error encountered save it to state and then call a backend api to post this error state to a file? or what would be the good idea. thanks.

Comment: yes, but if u r not using those errors on the client, why update the state with append log, just call the api with the data, and write a file on server.

Comment: this solution is not working. Material UI error is still shown in console